# SAML Bearer Grant fetching roles from SAML response

Tags: wso2, identityserver4, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Identity Server (6.1 version) and API Manager (4.2 version). I'm performing SAML Bearer Grant for my Spring Boot(3.1 version) Application, and I'm able to get the access token successfully after passing the SAML assertion to the /oauth2/token end point API. I'm able to get the below details after passing the Obtained access token in JWT.IO

```html
{
  "sub": "testuser",
  "aut": "APPLICATION_USER",
  "aud": "AklFbfGibZnUm5HEmfQzXrJo9qEa",
  "nbf": 1698948976,
  "azp": "AklFbfGibZnUm5HEmfQzXrJo9qEa",
  "scope": "openid",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9445/oauth2/token",
  "exp": 1698952576,
  "iat": 1698948976,
  "jti": "e43def79-67ce-40c7-ad53-c011bc658f2c",
  "client_id": "AklFbfGibZnUm5HEmfQzXrJo9qEa"
}
```

I'm able to get the username but my requirement here is i want to get the roles of the user as well, is there a possibility to fetch the roles of the user through

1. SAML Response or
2. Access Token.
   Can Anyone help me here. Any Help is highly Appreciated.